# User specific xorg.conf (without root access)

Tags: linux, xorg

I want to move the xorg config files (the ones in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`) into the home directory. I have gone through [this](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml), which suggests that only the root user can do that.If xorg is run in userspace (atleast in linux), why does the configuration need superuser permissions? Is there any other way to configure the xorg session without root access?